# Facebook SDK upgrading from 2.5 to 2.12

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

Before I would have a `Session fbSession;` object that I would get when logging in using the FacebookFragment.
And at log out from my app, in order to clean my session, I would do this.

```
if (PSSocialService.getInstance().fbSession != null) {
                PSSocialService.getInstance().fbSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            }
```

But now, there is no Session anymore. And the Login just gives me the LoginResult.
So I am trying to understand, if I want to logout of my app, how can I set that?

This is my current implementation of logging in, if it helps:

```
 fbButton.registerCallback(psSignInFlowActivity.mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            loginResult.getAccessToken();
            loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (PSApplicationClass.getInstance().pref.getUserId(getActivity()) == null)
                PSUser.authenticate(getActivity(), Constants.FB,   loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken(), null, loader, backFromAuth);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            // Handle exception
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new SDK found out that this is way more easier than expected.
You can simply logout of your FB session like this:

```
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```